# sectionname + number in header with fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I want to have section name + number on the left side in the header, and a predefined text on the right side. Also want to have `subsection` / `subsubsection name + number`, if the subsection is long enough. This is what I have.

```
\documentclass[11pt,norsk,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ucs,babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% title and so on

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}

\fancyhf{}

\rhead{\fancyplain{}{Prosessrapport}} % predefined ()
\lhead{\fancyplain{}{\rightmark }} % 1. sectionname, 1.1 subsection name etc
\cfoot{\fancyplain{}{\thepage}}
```

What I get from this, is the subsection name without number. And the subsection name + number.

UPDATE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,norsk,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ucs,babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\title{sd}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}

\fancyhf{}

\rhead{\fancyplain{}{$<$Name of the report$>$}} % predefined ()
\lhead{\fancyplain{}{\rightmark }} % 1. sectionname, 1.1 subsection name etc
\cfoot{\fancyplain{}{\thepage}}
\newpage
\section{section}
\newpage
\subsection{subsection}
\newpage
\subsubsection{subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

On the last page (4), I have a subsubsection, but the header says subsection. Is there any way to make it say subsubsection?

Comment: The argument of `\sectionmark` is only the title of the section. So if you want `\markright` to store also the number you must add it yourself: `\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}`. For the rest of your questions: Sort out your problem description first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This worked great for the section and subsection. But the subsubsection does not show up in the header. Any idea? :)

Comment: Make a *complete* example that demonstrates your problem. Also start comments with `@Ulrike` so that I get notified.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for your help! I have updated the post.

Comment: You can use `\renewcommand{\subsubsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsubsection\ #1}}` so that also the `\subsubsection` fills `\rightmark`. `\rightmark` will always show the *first* title of the page.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Would you turn your comment into an answer so as to move the question from the unanswered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\renewcommand{\subsubsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsubsection\ #1}}` so that also the `\subsubsection` fills `\rightmark`. `\rightmark` will always show the *first* title of the page.