# Problem with fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sectionname + number in header with fancyhdr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52027/sectionname-number-in-header-with-fancyhdr)

Uncustomised fancy page outputs at right head number and name of section.
When I type

```
\rhead{\thesection}
```

it outputs just a number of section :D

I just need page to output only name of section.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your question seems similar to [sectionname + number in header with fancyhdr](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52027/sectionname-number-in-header-with-fancyhdr). If this is the case, let us know so the question can be closed as duplicate; otherwise, please edit your question to say more about the problem. Don't feel bad if the question is a duplicate, it happens; we're waiting for other contributions from you, be they questions or answers.

Comment: @egreg: Very nice words indeed `:-)`

Comment: @egreg yep, It's really dublicate. But answer me one question, please and then close this question. What does this line do? "\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}"

Comment: @BogdanYaparov The line changes the way the section mark is displayed; in this case the mark will contain only the section title, without the number, which I don't think is a wise thing to do. The empty pair of braces should be removed.